# Recursive object message

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I have an Object structured like this:

```
{
  _id: {
    $oid: 'foo',
  },
  data: {
    john: {
     _doe: {
       $oid: 'bar'
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to massage this object so that it becomes:

```
{
  _id: 'foo',
  data: {
    john: {
     _doe: 'bar'
    }
  }
}
```

In other words, every instance of `$oid` should move that value up one level (or something like that). It could occur at many levels.

I tried:

```
var loop = function(o) {
    for ( var i in o ) {
        if ( i == '$oid' ) {
            o = o[i];
        } else if ( typeof o[i] == 'object' ) {
            loop(o[i]);
        }
    }
    return o;
}
loop(obj);
```

But it fails, and I can’t get my head around it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost have it, just needed a small fix:

```
var loop = function(o) {
    for ( var i in o ) {
        if ( i == '$oid' ) {
            o = o[i];
        } else if ( typeof o[i] == 'object' ) {
            console.log(o[i]);
            o[i] = loop(o[i]);
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

You need to assign the result of loop to the original object.

```
o[i] = loop(o[i]);
```

Comment: Assigning the return value is definitly the issue here!